# build custom docker image and execute desktop-application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, desktop-application, gnome

I need to do some test with the help of docker for a custom Ubuntu (containing the gnome-desktop) coming from my company. I've installed the Ubuntu with an iso file.

I tried to create an docker image with `iso` file but it doesn't seem to be possible.

So here is what I've done:

```
tar --numeric-owner --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys -cvf ubuntu.tar /
cat ubuntu.tar | docker import - ubuntu
```

After that, I can get the terminal of the image `ubuntu` that I just created. It's very huge (about 40 GB).

Now I need to execute an app, which needs a desktop environment because it has a GUI.

I've googled a lot to enable docker to execute GUI app. For now here is what I've tried:

```
xhost +localhost
docker run -ti -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw -e DISPLAY --device /dev/dri ubuntu bash
```

After executing the command above, I get an terminal of the container of the image `ubuntu`.

However, when I execute the GUI app with command line, I get the error:

> (gksudo:51): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: unix:0
>   Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or
>   directory
>   Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
>   Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display

So is it possible to execute a GUI app in docker container?

Comment: Are you executing the GUI app on Ubuntu? You can start GUI apps on Ubuntu (and centos too I think) but I didn't manage to make it work on windows or macos.

Comment: With the parameters here I was able to start a GUI app on ubuntu https://github.com/lvthillo/docker-franz . Maybe --net=host will fix your issue.

Comment: @lvthillo  thanks, I ll try.